# Cannot deploy contract containing KV Map API

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosio-code, eosio.cdt

I am following the example on how to use KV-Map-API from the official page, but when I call
`cleos set contract ...` I get following error message:

```
Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
env.kv_set unresolveable
pending console output:
```

EOS version is 2.1 and EOS.CDT is the latest one (v1.8.1). I have also tried to use normal `std::map` but I can only see values during the `upsert function`. When I call `find function` the map is empty. Here is the example with KV MAP:

```
 using my_map_t = eosio::kv::map<"kvmap"_n, string, string>;
 my_map_t my_map{};

 [[eosio::action]]
 void upsertrole(const string& role, const string account_name){
       my_map[role]=account_name;
 };
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

EOSIO Version 2.1 is obsolete, would not recommend to use it.

Use the AntelopeIO releases, latest is version 3.2. KV is not supported in AntelopeIO releases.

https://github.com/AntelopeIO/leap/releases/